# problema analizando wickionario xml

Tags: python, xml

Estoy intentando obtener un dataset en el que conste en una columna el nombre,en otra la definición(que se convertirá a variables dummy posteriormente)y en las restastes la clase de palabra que es(sustantivo,verbo, adverbio, pronombre,etc...)
Me descarge el volcado xml de wikimedia y he conseguido que aparezcan en una lista las palabras pero no la definición que aparece en un texto completo ejemplo:

[codigo xml de wikcionario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzuDw.png)

el codigo importante es el siguiente:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 tree = ET.parse('wikicom.xml')
 root = tree.getroot()
 x = []
 y = []
 for pagina in root.findall("page") :
   nombre=pagina.find("title").text
   exp=pagina.find("text").text
   y.append(exp) 
   x.append(nombre)
```

se ve que el campo text no lo puede traducir a texto y no puedo buscar en el texto lo que quiero.
si se le quita el .text al exp sale como una array sin indices
ah wikicom.xml es el archivo xml del volcado.

Answer (score 0):

conseguí lo que quería simplemente añadiéndole un /:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 tree = ET.parse('wikicom.xml')
 root = tree.getroot()
 x = []
 y = []
 for pagina in root.findall("page") :
   nombre=pagina.find("title").text
   definiciones=pagina.find("/text").text
   y.append(definiciones) 
   x.append(nombre)
```